# How can we give the value dynamically in VIEW of sql

Tags: java, sql, view

I created on view in that i want a dynamic value which is entered by user in front end

```
 ROUND((sysdate - io.movementdate), 2) AS TotalDays,
```

In above line it is taking sysdate but i want the date which is entered by user

Comment: A view has no input values.

Answer (score 0):

A value cannot have input.
You should create a stored procedure that returns a query result, like a view. But in a stored you can provide input parameters.

For example (assuming your db vendor is SqlServer):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testProcedure]
@param int
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE id = @param;
GO
```

And you can call this with:

```
exec testProcedure 34;
```

Where 34 is the value you want to pass.

Comment: Can you please give me an example. because i am new for stored procedure